# Patterns not appearing while using highcharts export server?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, export

I am using Highcharts Export Server with the pattern plugin. While it works all fine with the normal graphs and helps exporting but when we have custom patterns it does not apply those custom patterns in the exported png image.

The plugin is https://github.com/highcharts/pattern-fill

The HTTP Request carries the json config for the graph.

Comment: Provide us with the example where it does not work. I exported a chart using custom patterns with success. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nhbLjqn0/.

Comment: @d_paul I am talking about the Export Server. If you set up your own export server this happens